# How to merge two DataFrame containing same keys but different values in same columns in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, concatenation

I have one dataframe that contains all ids

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['A01', 'A02', 'A03', 'A04', 'A05', 'A06','A07'],
                        'Name': ['', '', '', '', 'MKI', 'OPU','']})
```

Second DataFrame that contains some Ids has different name in them

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['A01', 'A05', 'A06', 'A03'],
                    'Name': ['ABC', 'TUV', 'MNO', 'JKL']})
```

I want to merge both of them , where same Ids where one contains some name replace empty name and merge

**Also DF2 name have to consider while merging**

MERGE OUTPUT DF:-

```
df3 = {'id': ['A01', 'A02', 'A03', 'A04', 'A05', 'A06','A07'],
       'Name': ['ABC','', 'JKL','', 'TUV', 'MNO','']}
```

Note:- Merge two dataframe with same columns and some same id but different name, if it's empty replace it other dataframe value ,Also get two value for same id then replace it with DF2
**consider DF2 as MAIN** , and **want all data of Df1**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use left join by only `df1['id']` column and replace missing values by empty strings:

```
df = df1[['id']].merge(df2, on='id', how='left').fillna({'Name':''})
print (df)
    id Name
0  A01  ABC
1  A02     
2  A03  JKL
3  A04     
4  A05  TUV
5  A06  MNO
6  A07
```